# ZFS on Linux for RHEL/OEL NFS Sharing

Tags: nfs, zfs, rhel6

I'm trying ZFS on Linux for Oracle Linux (OLE) 6.1 (Red Hat RHEL 6.1 compatible clone).
I successfully compiled and installed **spl** and **zfs** on it for Oracle Unbreakable Kernel.
Zfs is working and I created mirror by

```
zpool create -f -o ashift=12 tank mirror sdb sdc
```

Now I'm trying to share my zfs pool caled "tank/nfs" as mentioned at [zfsonlinux site](http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#HowDoISetupShares).

```
zfs set sharenfs=on tank/nfs
```

So I created **tank/nfs** and set **nfs** to **on**.

Now I'm trying to mount nfs share at local host to test it by

```
mount -t nfs4 127.0.0.1:/tank/nfs /mnt
```

But I get `mount.nfs4: mount system call failed`

So question is:

***How to share NFS Folder* or iSCSI Volumes at OLE rightly and mount it *with Linux Client via ZFS* on Linux.**

the answer is
`mount 127.0.0.1:/tank/nfs /mnt`

Comment: Can you try this from a different client that the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your nfs server configuration.

Please try following this [howto](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_NFS_to_Share_RHEL_6_Folders_with_Remote_Linux_and_UNIX_Systems) for setting up RHEL 6 as an nfs server.

Comment: Thanks for the HOWTO. The right answer is: `mount 127.0.0.1:/tank/nfs /mnt`

Comment: @BBK If you have solved your problem please either accept an answer or add your own and accept it.

Comment: zfs set sharenfs="rw=@10.x.x.x/24,no_root_squash,no_all_squash" tank/share   Is an example  also make sure to punch holes in the firewall as it will block traffic   firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=111/tcp   is an example

Answer (score 4):

In order to establish an NFS mount, you need to have the `portmap` service running before attempting the mount.

Run `/sbin/service portmap start` and retry your NFS mount.

For RHEL6 and newer, this is in `rpcbind` - `/sbin/service rpcbind start`

Comment: portmap: unrecognized service. yum install portmap. 
Package rpcbind-0.2.0-8.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Oh, for RHEL6, try `/sbin/service rpcbind start` instead.

Comment: rpcbind (pid  1692) is running... `mount -t nfs4 127.0.0.1:/tank/nfs /mnt` mount.nfs4: mount system call failed

Comment: This is getting too chatty. Try an `nfs` mount instead of `nfs4`. Also check that you don't have anything blocking the nfs ports (see `rpcinfo -p`). Since you're using the ZFS on Linux add-on, I don't know if you need to `exportfs -a` or not. Either way, this is probably not the *best idea* if you plan to use for production, given the state of the project.

Comment: check, too, your hosts.allow and hosts.deny configurations

Comment: It is clean system. hosts.allow and hosts.deny contain nothing. Iptables turned off.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience with ZFS on FreeBSD and Debian GNU/kFreeBSD, I found that the sharenfs feature was not implemented well. You may set up your NFS exports in /etc/exports.

Each ZFS filesystem that you want to export needs its own export line. We found this to be too slow with hundreds of filesystems. You should also try using a single filesystem as though you were using a traditional filesystem.

### NFS exports in Linux

You will have to edit the /etc/exports file to enable NFS in Linux. With NFSv4 in Linux, every exported filesystem must be mounted under a single directory called the NFSv4 pseudofilesystem. In this case, that would be /tank. Mountpoints under the pseudofilesystem can be exported with different access control methods and export options. Any filesystems mounted under the psuedofilesystem must get its own export line in /etc/exports.

/etc/exports:

```
/tank *(fsid=0)
/tank/nfs *(rw,sync)
```

To make changes to /etc/exports take effect, you should run `exportfs -r`.

For NFSv4 you will need to run idmapd on both the client and the server to facilitate mapping from username to user id number.

In Linux NFSv4, the export is different than with NFSv3 and lower. Given that the pseudofilesystem is /tank, your mount command would be:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=4 server:/nfs /mnt
```

For NFSv3, it would be:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=3 server:/tank/nfs /mnt
```

Comment: I need hostname in `/etc/exports: /tank 127.0.0.1(fsid=0)
/tank/nfs 127.0.0.1(rw,sync)`. But `mount -t nfs -o vers=4 server:/nfs /mnt` saying **mount.nfs: mount system call failed**. And `mount -t nfs -o vers=3 127.0.0.1:/tank/nfs /mnt` saying **mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported**

Comment: Have you tried turning off iptables or explicitly allowing tcp port 2049 on localhost? I'm surprised that the default rules would block anything on localhost, but it is what Googling that error message suggests.

Comment: iptables turned off.

Comment: `mount -t nfs -o vers=3 127.0.0.1:/tank/nfs /mnt`
_mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported_. `mount -t nfs -o vers=4 127.0.0.1:/nfs /mnt`
_mount.nfs: mount system call failed_

Comment: /etc/exports: `/tank 127.0.0.1(fsid=0)
/tank/nfs 127.0.0.1(rw,sync)`

Comment: I made an incorrect assumption with this answer. I'm leaving it up because it may still be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing ZFS natively on Solaris or SolE 11 or OpenIndiana. In my opinion ZFS on Linux is nowhere close to being in any shape, ready for production. ZFS with NFS have native integration on Solaris-based OS's, but not  so on Linux.

Comment: OP wants to know how to do something with ZFS+NFS under Linux. Advising him to use Solaris & Co. is not an useful answer. Besides the ZFS support is nowadays dimensions better than it was back then.